# How do I disable the text selection icon in the mouse cursor?

Tags: debian, terminal, rxvt

I'm having some trouble when trying to personalize the way my terminal works.
I would like to not show the text selection icon when I enter into the terminal, and only show the default cursor instead.
The terminal I'm using is URXVT with a Linux Debian System.
Thank you so much for your help.